# Elephants in first order logic

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic

I have as facts these (el stands for elephant):

```
el(Sam)    el(Clyde)    el(Oscar)
pink(Sam)
gray(Clyde)  likes(Clyde, Oscar)
pink(Oscar)Vgray(Oscar)    likes(Oscar, Sam)
```

Now, I want to prove(?) that: *Some gray elephant likes some pink elephant*, which translates to: (exists x)(el(x) /\ gray(x) /\ (exists y) (el(y) /\ pink(y) /\ likes(x, y)). So, we need to take its negation and resolve(?) it into the basis, in order to reach void(?).

The negation is (will use `~` to show negation):

```
~el(x) V ~gray(x) V ~el(y) V ~pink(y) V ~likes(x, y)
```

The way I see it, I shall assign `x` and `y` values (Sam, Clyde or Oscar) and insert the later statement in the base, to "kill" the facts that lie there already.

My attempt:

I set `x = Clyde, y = Oscar`, which gave me:

```
~el(Clyde) V ~gray(Clyde) V ~el(Oscar) V ~pink(Oscar) V ~likes(Clyde, Oscar)
```

which if I put into the base, "kill" their "pairs" and the base becomes:

```
el(Sam)
pink(Sam)
gray(Oscar)    likes(Oscar, Sam)
```

and now what? We run out of elephants!

Ideally, I would like to have `x' = Oscar, y' = Sam`, so that I would get:

```
~el(Oscar) V ~gray(Oscar) V ~el(Sam) V ~pink(Sam) V ~likes(Oscar, Sam)
```

which would go into the base and kill everything, but `~el(Oscar)` would still be alive! How should I proceed?

---

Follow-up question:

Base:

```
a
b
c V d
```

and then I put into the bases `~a/\~b/\~c/\~d`. Everything in the base will be vanished in the same way? I mean wouldn't the `V` operator affect things?

Comment: how this question relates to Prolog ?

Comment: We did that in the course of Prolog @CapelliC.

Comment: @gsamaras If your interest in this is theoretical then [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a more fitted site for your question

Comment: @sokin thanks: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48087/elephants-in-first-order-logic

Comment: Please spend some more time reworking and polishing it. As it is now, each paragraph is so full of sloppyness errors it hurts! Most importantly, do not try using fuzzy pseudo code to illustrate your point. It never works. Instead try using valid ISO Prolog term syntax! Don't be afraid of making errors; people here will gladly help you!

Comment: @repeat I didn't use any pseudocode, this is just as we write on your textbox. Also, I am not really sure about what errors you talk about.

Comment: Ok. (1) Take `el(Sam)    el(Clyde)    el(Oscar)`: after each one of these facts  a period (full-stop) is missing.(2) `Sam`, `Clyde`, and `Oscar` are Prolog *variables*, not atoms like either `sam` or `'Sam'`. (3) `x' = Oscar, y' = Sam` is invalid syntax, looks more like OCaml than Prolog to me. Prolog variables may not include ticks `'` (4) `Vgray` is bad syntax. (5) `/\` is used for bitwise integer "and". (6) Having an operator `V` is bad design. (7) "(exists x)(el(x) /\ gray(x) /\ (exists y) (el(y) /\ pink(y) /\ likes(x, y))" should b typeset differently to indicate code /math logic formula.

Comment: Or are you saying that the snippets you gave are not even supposed valid Prolog syntax?

Comment: @repeat they are not even Prolog. I am sorry for your long comment! But it's OK for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have something like this:

```
 el(sam).
 el(clyde).
 el(oscar).
 pink(sam).
 grey(clyde).
 likes(clyde,oscar).
 likes(oscar,sam).
 canbe(oscar,grey).
 canbe(oscar,pink).

 gelephant_likes_pelephant(GE,PE):-
   grey(GE),el(GE),
   pink(PE),el(PE),
   likes(GE,PE).


 gelephant_likes_pelephant(GE,PE):-
   canbe(GE,grey),el(GE),
   pink(PE),el(PE),
   likes(GE,PE).

gelephant_likes_pelephant(GE,PE):-
  grey(GE),el(GE),
  canbe(PE,pink),el(PE),
  likes(GE,PE).
```

Qs:

```
?- gelephant_likes_pelephant(GE,PE).
GE = oscar,
PE = sam ;
GE = clyde,
PE = oscar.
```

You have to be careful how you use a predicate like canbe/2. As it is saying oscar can be grey or pink. Then my query is saying which grey elephants like which pink elephants, the answer can be interpreted as: IF oscar is a grey elephant THEN oscar likes sam OR IF clyde likes oscar THEN oscar is a pink elephant.

Comment: OK I see who you solve it, but still I can't see how this answers my question. I mean, I am asking theoretically here. Maybe your answer helps, but I still can't see how! :/

Comment: In some sense the query gelephant_likes_pelephant(GE,PE). proves the question 'Some gray elephant likes some pink elephant,' as it gives an answer. But like I say you should read the answers as If statements.In general prolog uses horn logic so it can only have one literal in the head. You can sometimes do better with ASP for cases like this as you can have two literals in the head and show all the models. Otherwise you can also use dif/2 to get answers with constraints.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. However it doesn't answer my question still.

Comment: Ok I am not understanding your question.. can you rephrase?

Comment: Thank u for your patience. I want to theoretically prove the statement, in the paper. I mean, if you look at my answer I perform a paritcular approach (hope I am on the right track( and then I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_model_semantics
You compute the reduct of the program and then look to see if the expression you want to prove is in every stable model.